# GUID in databases other than SQL Server

Tags: sql, nhibernate, database-design, orm, auto-increment

Question: I'm planning the database for one of my programs at the moment.

I intend to use ASP.NET MVC for the user backend, the database being on Linux and/or on Windows.

Now, even if I would only make it for windows, I had to take into account, that different customers use different database systems. Now, I figured I use nHibernate, then I can put everything in the code, and it works on all mayor databases, such as Oracle/Sybase/MS/PostGre/MySQL/Firebird.

My probem now is GUIDs. SQL Server uses GUIDs, while the rest uses integer auto-increment as primary keys. While auto-increment is better in theory, it creates problems keeping multiple databases in sync, or problems manually changing things, which requires CSV import/export...

Now, because of the inherent problems with autoid in practise, I like the GUID system better. And since a guid is a 36-character string, I could use varchar(36) as a primary-key, but a varchar as GUID, might just not be an ideal solution...

How would you solve this problem/what do you use as primary-key ?
Or how do you evade the auto-increment problems, say insert a csv file without changing the autoid...

Comment: Just don't use your GUID's as Primary/Clustering Key in SQL Server - see why here: http://www.sqlskills.com/BLOGS/KIMBERLY/post/GUIDs-as-PRIMARY-KEYs-andor-the-clustering-key.aspx

Comment: But..., if auto-id + GUID is not a good idea, what then ?

Comment: I think you will find that GUIDs can create a much bigger mess than autoincrementing integer IDs (which SQL Server also has BTW).

Comment: How can GUIDs create a mess? I know that importing a previously exported CSV file with autoinc. integer creates a big mess, since it changes all primary keys, which are referenced elsewhere...
but GUIDs, how can you create a mess with them ?
I'd like to know how...

Answer (score 2):

A Guid key using the `guid.comb` generator key is usable in any database, even if it doesn't have Guid as a native type.

Answer (score 0):

You could also consider generating a primary key which is a combination of auto-increment (i.e. setting up a sequence) and an unique identifier of the machine it was generated on, maybe using the MAC address.

See [this](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Universally_unique_identifier) for a discussion.

This way you have a locally unique (thanks to the sequence) ID which is also globally unique (thanks to the MAC address part).

I know, I know, [you can spoof a MAC address](http://www.mydigitallife.info/2008/06/30/how-to-change-or-spoof-mac-address-in-windows-xp-vista-server-20032008-mac-os-x-unix-and-linux/) but it's up to you to decide if this is really a risk in your domain. Also, the ability to spoof it could be handy when you test your code.

---

Please explain better what happens when a new customer DB is born. Will it be registered on the Server? If yes, you can assign a DB-id on the server, and use it in lieu of the MAC address, just assign a number to each new DB and use it along with the sequence.

Basically, if you want an "unique DB instance ID" to avoid "table id" collisions, you have only two choices:

1) Server assigns the DB ID whenever a new DB is added

2) Client autogenerate a unique ID, and this usually needs using the MAC address, either "raw" or processed somehow.

I honestly can't see alternatives given your current description of your problem.

Comment: The MAC-address GUID part has been removed in .NET (in SP 1 I think).
It's not a good idea, since if the user gets a GUID (sent to his machine), he can reconstruct the server MAC address, which opens the door to all kind of abuses. And certainly, combining a GUID with an auto-increment would be an ultra-stupid idea, since it combines the problems of both systems, GUID and auto-increment...

Comment: I don't know enough of your scenario to offer specific advice - it depends on how the application is used: if you are sure that there is always one distinct server you may replace its MAC address part with an arbitratry number (e.g. zero). And you may also use a one-way encoding function on the MAC address. Maybe if you explain in more detail the server/nodes the relationship I can be more specific. If a new node is registered to the server you can drop the mac address and just assign a sort of "site-id" to each satellite DB.

Comment: I tried to explain this a bit better, check the revised answer.

Answer (score 0):

Oracle and PostgreSQL support GUIDs as well, there is no need so use sequences there (and of course Diego is right: if you use your own algorithm to create GUIDs you can always store use a varchar column with your own generated GUID)

Note that it's spelled PostgreSQL, never PostGre

Answer (score 0):

I have never had any trouble using Guids. We used Guid.Comb in a system with many records (millions) and had no trouble because of the Guids themselves. The selling point for me is that I can generate the Ids before i persist something to the database. Even on the client. Which is very helpful in CQRS scenarios.
The only thing that I think you should also consider is human readability. It's hard to look at the database and match records in a lets say master/detail scenario.

And a note on Firebird... Uuid is written as an octet. And most clients that I've used to manage the database can't represent those in a decent format. So it's usually just displayed as a couple of characters (probably by just decoding a byte array as a string). I don't know about other providers though. SQLServer Management Studio for example shows them just fine.

Comment: Since he is using NHibernate, his bigint/int ids can also be generated before going to the db by using the hilo algorithm.

Comment: Indeed. There is another issue with that though. If you have entities encapsulated in lists in other entities then those child entities get their IDs assigned when NHibernate is persisting them. With Guids all entities have their IDs assigned on object instantiation.
Or in other words you only get IDs when you call MakePersistent or your equivalent.